# Long int to Javascript date format

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a long int value: 20140307080000. This is actually the datetime 2014-03-07 08:00:00. I've tried Date.parse in JS as it is and after converting it to a string, but, I cannot retrieve it as a Javascript date object. Is there any javascript or D3 built in method to convert this to a date object rather than manually splitting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Your date String
var d = "20140307080000";

// Convert it to the format 2014-03-07 08:00:00
var f = d.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6");

// Alerting after parse
alert(new Date(Date.parse(f)));

// This will alert "Fri Mar 07 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"
```

Comment: Cant believe it was that simple. Manual, but elegant. Wow.